# Not abstract and does not override abstract method punctuate(long)

Tags: java

I have following interface implementation:

```
package io.khinkali.topology;

import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.*;

public class PathsProcessor<K, V> implements ProcessorSupplier {

  @Override
  public Processor get() {
    return new Processor() {

      private StateStore state;

      @Override
      public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.state = context.getStateStore("myProcessorState");
        context.schedule(1000, PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, System.out::println);
      }

      @Override
      public void process(K key, V value) {

      }

      @Override
      public void close() {

      }
    };
  }
}
```

the compiler complains:

```
[error] /home/developer/Desktop/microservices/bary-paths-stream/src/main/scala/io/khinkali/topology/PathsProcessor.java:9:1: <anonymous io.khinkali.topology.PathsProcessor$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method punctuate(long) in org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.Processor
[error]     return new Processor<K, V>() {
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) javac returned non-zero exit code
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Nov 21, 2017 9:46:47 AM
```

The Processor looks as following:

```
public interface Processor<K, V> {

    void init(ProcessorContext context);
    void process(K key, V value);
    @Deprecated
    void punctuate(long timestamp);
    void close();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method:

```
@Deprecated
void punctuate(long timestamp);
```

still needs to be implemented even though it is deprecated.

EDIT: Deprecated only means that the method should not be used in new code because the plan is to remove it in the future. The annotation is meant to warn developers about this fact. However, as long as the method is there in the interface, it must still be implemented by any implementation. I agree that this could be confusing: you should not use the method and at the same time you must implement it. This is the life of a developer.

Comment: Why it needs to implemented, when it is deprecated?

Answer (score 2):

The annonymous class that you have return is of type [Processor](https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/Processor.html), which as you mentioned has 4 methods that its implementors must implement,

**Note:** that [Deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html) is just a marker to indicate that it is discouraged from being used. Yet it doesn't mean that you can skip implementing it as every method irrespective of its annotations are `public` & `abstract`.